# How does config.assets.resolve_with work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

The explanation in the documentation doesn't make sense to me.

1. What does `:environment` do/mean, exactly?
2. Is there anything other than `:manifest` and `:environment`?

---

[Documentation](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#initializer-options):

> `config.assets.resolve_with`
>
> A list of `:environment` and `:manifest` symbols that defines the order that we try to find assets: manifest first, environment second? Manifest only?
>
> By default, we check the manifest first if asset digests are enabled and debug is not enabled, then we check the environment if compiling is enabled:

```
# Dev where debug is true, or digests are disabled
%i[ environment ]

# Dev default, or production with compile enabled.
%i[ manifest environment ]

# Production default.
%i[ manifest ]
```

> If the resolver list is empty (e.g. if debug is true and compile is false), the standard rails public path resolution will be used.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/397